# GNU awk, FPAT and trouble with a duplicating FS

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a `file`:

```
$ cat file
1,,"3.1,3.2",4,5
```

and because of the quotes I'm using [`FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) instead of just `FS=","`. I'm trying to replace a field, lets say `$4`, with another value:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS=","}{$4="new"; print}' file
1,,"3.1,3.2",new,,5
$ # right here  ^
```

but I get a duplicated `,` (`OFS`) after the replaced field. It gets duplicated when modifying any field except last field or empty fields.

Are you guys seeing this or is it just me in need of glasses 8| ? I'm using GNU Awk 4.1.3.

**Edit:**

A-ha, it must be an old bug. 4.1.1 duplicates the comma but 4.1.4 doesn't.

Comment: My output (GNU awk 4.1.4) is `1,,"3.1,3.2",new,5` (no extra comma)

Comment: Ok, I'll try a more recent version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug in GNU awk prior to version 4.1.4.

Comment: Answering this myself to close the question and to keep the info available here.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this question at the time but in particular, it's this bug up to 4.1.3: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2015-09/msg00033.html. Note that the fix for that bug caused this other bug in 4.1.4: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-04/msg00000.html so get yourself onto gawk 4.2 if you're using FPAT :-).