# Nullify fields in pipe delimited file

Tags: parsing, awk, pipe, delimited

Am not able to get the desired o/p when the data field has pipe in it.

```
If the i/p is 
SAmple file is tst
hdr1|"hdr2|tst"|"hdr3|tst|tst"|hdr4|"hdr5|tst|tst"
lbl1|"lbl2|tst"|"lbl3|tst|tst"|lbl4|"lbl5|tst|tst"

I tried with this cmd but dont get the expected o/p - cut -f2,3 -d"|" tst

The expected o/p is 
"hdr2|tst"|"hdr3|tst|tst"
"lbl2|tst"|"lbl3|tst|tst"
```

Is there an easy way that we can crack this o/p...Dont want to go with sed bcoz the tool that am using doesnt allow the charecter (""- backslash). I mean am embedding this command in one of the tool
Also am using old version of gawk -

```
so this cmd doesnt give te desired o/p
gawk -v FPAT='[^|]*|("[^"]*")+' '{print $2, $3}' OFS="|"

Output of gawk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7

Output of cat -vet tst

hdr1|"hdr2|tst"|"hdr3|tst|tst"|hdr4|"hdr5|tst|tst"$
lbl1|"lbl2|tst"|"lbl3|tst|tst"|lbl4|"lbl5|tst|tst"$
```

Comment: Looks to be bug in the GNU awk version you have with using FPAT. Per this comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031764/gnu-awk-fpat-and-trouble-with-a-duplicating-fs#comment91438732_50017685, suggest upgrading your gawk to 4.2+ if you are using FPAT

Comment: It's not a bug, FPAT just wasn't introduced until gawk 4.0 and the OP is on gawk 3.1.7 (which is about 10 years out of date!)

Comment: @EdMorton: Oops! didn't know that. In any case, upgrading to a latter release is one option for OP

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading your gawk version is by far the best approach as you're missing a few bug fixes and a ton of extremely useful functionality introduced since gawk 3.1.7 came out 10+ years ago (we're currently on gawk version 5.1!) but if you can't do that for some reason then - here's what you can do if you don't have `FPAT` using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="|" }
{
    orig = $0
    $0 = i = ""
    while ( (orig != "") && match(orig,/[^|]*|("[^"]*")+/) ) {
        $(++i) = substr(orig,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        orig = substr(orig,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
    }
    print $2, $3
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"hdr2|tst"|"hdr3|tst|tst"
"lbl2|tst"|"lbl3|tst|tst"
```

Just to verify that it's identifying all of the fields correctly:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="|" }
{
    orig = $0
    $0 = i = ""
    while ( (orig != "") && match(orig,/[^|]*|("[^"]*")+/) ) {
        $(++i) = substr(orig,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        orig = substr(orig,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
    }

    print NF " <" $0 ">"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print "\t" i " <" $i ">"
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
5 <hdr1|"hdr2|tst"|"hdr3|tst|tst"|hdr4|"hdr5|tst|tst">
        1 <hdr1>
        2 <"hdr2|tst">
        3 <"hdr3|tst|tst">
        4 <hdr4>
        5 <"hdr5|tst|tst">
5 <lbl1|"lbl2|tst"|"lbl3|tst|tst"|lbl4|"lbl5|tst|tst">
        1 <lbl1>
        2 <"lbl2|tst">
        3 <"lbl3|tst|tst">
        4 <lbl4>
        5 <"lbl5|tst|tst">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Instead of creating (.awk script)  - is there any other way to get the desired result or can we have an alternate way to fix this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but if it's how to execute the awk script without storing it in a file that's just `awk 'script' file` instead of `awk -f tst.awk file`. See the awk man page and try `awk 'BEGIN{print "Hello World"}'` if you're not sure what I mean.

Comment: I got this. But my question was , is there a shortcut to get the o/p

Comment: Yes, update your gawk version and use FPAT. Otherwise I guess we'll find out if you get any shorter answers.

Comment: @AbdulWahabKhan, please stop leaching answers from multiple forums - similar/same points/comments have already been made and A solution has been provided.

Comment: @AbdulWahabKhan I'm curious though - why do you care how short the script is?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have embedded double quotes, you can substitute the quoted delimiter values with another unused character (I used `~`) and after extraction switch back to the original values.  Obviously it requires that the new delimiter is not used within text.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\""} {for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2) gsub("\\|","~",$i)}1' file | 
  awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}  {print $2,$3}'                                 | 
  sed 's/~/|/g' 

"hdr2|tst"|"hdr3|tst|tst"
"lbl2|tst"|"lbl3|tst|tst"
```

Not sure it's simpler than the single `awk` script though.

Main problem here is the document format design.  Requires another patch if there are embedded double quotes, or escaped pipes etc.

Comment: The OP said whatever environment they're in doesn't allow them to use backslashes in scripts (`the tool that am using doesnt allow the charecter (""- backslash)`) so that may need a tweak or 2. Btw the first argument for `gsub()` is a regexp, not a string, so if you used regexp delimiters then you wouldn't have needed to double up on the escapes (`gsub(/\|/...`)